# usbip does not work with USB Debugging in Android phone

Tags: usb, android, adb

I want to connect a Samsung Android phone to a remote server over usbip and then build an Android application located on the server device to the phone to do some testing. I came accross the usbip utility which can connect a device to a remote machine over IP. I can connect my device properly using the following commands and outputs and see it connected on the server machine:

On host device (my pc)

> ```
> root@emir-work:~$ usbip bind -b 1-5
> usbip: info: bind device on busid 1-5: complete
>
> root@emir-work:~$ usbip list -r localhost
> Exportable USB devices
> ======================
>  - localhost
>         1-5: Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd : Galaxy series, misc. (MTP mode) (04e8:6860)
>            : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5
>            : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)
> ```

On remote device (server)

> ```
> root[~] # usbip list -r 192.168.0.184
> Exportable USB devices
> ======================
>  - 192.168.0.184
>         1-5: Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd : Galaxy series, misc. (MTP mode) (04e8:6860)
>            : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5
>            : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)
>
> root[~] # usbip attach -r 192.168.0.184 -b 1-5
> ```

After these commands I can access the phone from the server device and see the contents etc. However Android Debugging Bridge does not recognize the device since USB debugging option is not enabled. The connection immediately drops when I enable USB debugging, and the device is automatically unbind from usbip on the host device. When try to bind it again it does not show up in the exportable USB devices list and does not bind.

Here are the relevant journalctl logs on the host machine:

```
Eki 30 10:18:56 emir-work ModemManager[1091]: <info>  [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5': not supported by any plugin
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work gvfsd[3747621]: Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work dbus-daemon[2259]: [session uid=1000 pid=2259] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer'
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work dbus-daemon[2259]: [session uid=1000 pid=2259] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=2482 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " lab>
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work gvfsd[3747831]: Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work snapd[1031]: hotplug.go:200: hotplug device add event ignored, enable experimental.hotplug
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work colord[2177]: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work colord[2177]: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work colord[2177]: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work kernel: cdc_acm 1-5:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work kernel: usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 330069a3272ba2a5
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work kernel: usb 1-5: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work kernel: usb 1-5: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work kernel: usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Eki 30 10:18:54 emir-work kernel: usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860, bcdDevice= 4.00
Eki 30 10:18:53 emir-work kernel: usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 123 using xhci_hcd
Eki 30 10:18:53 emir-work kernel: usbip-host 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 122
```

And journalctl logs in the remote machine:

```
Eki 30 10:18:36 android-devel gvfsd[10990]: Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel systemd-udevd[11072]: 2-1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/platform/vhci_hcd.0/usb2/2-1 189:134' failed with exit code 1.
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel systemd-udevd[11072]: 2-1: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/platform/vhci_hcd.0/usb2/2-1 189:134' failed with exit code 1.
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel systemd-udevd[11072]: 2-1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/platform/vhci_hcd.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel systemd-udevd[11072]: 2-1:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/platform/vhci_hcd.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel kernel: usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 7
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel kernel: vhci_hcd: disconnect device
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel kernel: vhci_hcd: release socket
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel kernel: vhci_hcd: stop threads
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel kernel: vhci_hcd: connection closed
Eki 30 10:18:34 android-devel gvfsd[10990]: PTP: reading event an error 0x05 occurred
```

usbip deamon on debug mode does not show any warnings or error when this behavior occurs.

May be important to note that `usbip version` outputs `(usbip-utils 2.0)` on both machines.
Finaly, both machines run Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and the Android Studio version on the remote machine is 2022.3.1